# How to convert two's complement binary to decimal in MIPS

Tags: assembly, binary, converters, mips, twos-complement

I'm reading in binary machine code from a file and translating it back into assembly instructions and am having problems with negative immediate values (last 16 bits of an I-Type instruction). I am reading the line in 1 bit at a time and converting the binary numbers into decimal numbers as I go on using this function:

```
readBits:   #Function to read bits
    add $t5, $a0, $zero     #set t5 to parameter
    li $t1, 2             #base value (2)
    li $t7 , 0            #j = 0
    li $s0, 0             # Set return value to 0
    li $s7, '0'           # load ascii value of '0'
    readBitsLoop:
        beq $t7, $t5, endReadBitsLoop   #If we are past our length's iteration, we have rs
        lb $t2, fileInputBuffer($t0)    #Load in byte in file
        addi $t0, $t0, 1       # iterator for file++
        addi $t7, $t7, 1       # j++
        mult $s0, $t1          #multiply return value and base
        mflo $t3              #set result to t5
        sub $t4, $t2, $s7   #subtract fileInputBuffer[i] and ascii value for '0'
        add $s0, $t3,$t4        #Add those 2 together

        j readBitsLoop      #Jump to start of loop
        endReadBitsLoop:
            add $v0, $s0, $zero #move return value to return register
            jr $ra  #go back to where we were
```

This function takes in an input of how long that section should be. For example, for the immediate value, the parameter would be 16.

This works fine for positive values, but not for negative ones because I need to complement it before parsing. Is there an easy way to do this? Or is there some way to do that conversion after it's already in decimal?

Thanks for any help with this. Let me know if you need to see more code to understand what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean "decimal" as in ASCII or as in [binary coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal)?

Comment: @tadman I'm not exactly sure, but I think it's ASCII. When I output the register with the "decimal" value using syscall mode 1, it prints as a base 10 number such as 25.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you actually want is to [sign-extend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) a 16-bit signed 2's complement integer to a 32-bit signed 2's complement integer that fills a register, so you can use it with add / sub / multiply instructions.

You only need to convert to decimal if you want to print it as a string (i.e. do what `v0=1` `syscall` does yourself.)

Anyway, an arithmetic right shift is one way to make copies of the sign bit.  First left shift your narrow integer so its sign bit is at the left of the register, then use an arithmetic shift.

```
#  $s0 = all 4 bytes of a 32-bit I-type instruction
# where the immediate is the low 16 bits.
sll  $t3,  $s0, 16             # shift left logical
sra  $t3,  $t3, 16             # shift right arithmetic
# $t3 = a 32-bit integer from -65536 to +65535 = the immediate
# $t3 = sign_extend(low16($s0))
```

MIPS instructions are always aligned, so you can safely `lw` the whole instruction or `lh` the low half, without needing to combine the two 8-bit halves of the immediate with two `lb` instructions and a shift/OR.

---

And BTW, you're reading one *byte* at a time, not one bit.  `addi` by 1 advances `$t0` by a whole byte every loop iteration.

```
    lb $t2, fileInputBuffer($t0)    #Load in byte in file
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
```

You appear to be using `mult` by a constant `2` instead of a left-shift.  This is highly inefficient.  Even better, you can left shift by adding a number to itself.  `addu $t3, $s0, $s0` does `$t3 = $s0 << 1 = $s0 * 2`.

See [the basic MIPS instruction set](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).